# Read partioned hive table in pyspark instead of a parquet

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, hiveql

I have a partionned parquet. It is partioned by date like:

```
/server/my_dataset/dt=2021-08-02
/server/my_dataset/dt=2021-08-01
/server/my_dataset/dt=2021-07-31
...
```

The size is huge, so I do not want to read it at the time and I need only august part, therefore I use:

```python
spark.read.parquet("/server/my_dataset/dt=2021-08*")
```

It works just fine. However I am forced to move from reading parquet directly to reading from the corresponding hive table. Something like:

```python
spark.read.table("schema.my_dataset")
```

However I want to keep the same logic of reading only certain partitions of the data. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`filter`** and **`like`** operator.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.read.table("schema.my_dataset").filter(col("dt").like("2021-08%"))
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

You can get all the **august partition values** into a variable then use filter query with in statement.

**`Example:`**

```
#get the partition values into variable and filter required
val lst=df.select("dt").distinct.collect().map(x => x(0).toString)

#then use isin function to filter only required partitions
df.filter(col("dt").isin(lst:_*)).show()
```

**`For python sample code:`**

```
lst=[1,2]
df.filter(col("dt").isin(*lst)).show()
```

Comment: This was the first thing I used to do with parquets, but this caused huge perfomance issue because the dataset got loaded and then filtered, whereas reading only certain partitions of the dataset allowed the dataset to be processed much faster.

Comment: So I was thinking that may bee there is some way to tell read.table to read only certain partitions...

Comment: @GrigorySharkov, check my updated answer!